# Django Channels : Login to the session using consumer not working

Tags: django, django-channels, django-sessions

I have a SPA built using django channels and Vue for frontend.

The very first time user loads the webpage, the index.html is served using

```
url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name="app")
```

Then frontend communicates with the server using web socket.

One of the messages sent could be to **login** into the system with appropriate credentials.

I have been following instructions at https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html to implement login through the consumer.

```
class MyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.group_name = str(uuid.uuid1())
        print(self.scope['session'].session_key)
        self.user = self.scope["user"]

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

        # User data
        await self.send(simplejson.dumps(dict(data=dict(socketid=self.group_name, user=dict(username=self.user.username or None)))))

    async def receive_json(self, jsdata):       
        kwargs = jsdata.get('kwargs', {})

        # Manage Login
        if is_login_message(jsdata): # This checks if the message is sent to do login
            user = authenticate(**kwargs)
            await login(self.scope, user)
            print('Saving login session')
            await database_sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()
            await self.send(simplejson.dumps(dict(data=dict(user=dict(username=user.username)))))
            print(self.scope['session'].session_key)
            return
```

Everything works fine. I could see the seesion key being printed when user logs in. However, when I reload the web page, the session is not retained. It prints None in the **connect** method. I see the cookies are not getting set after the login is done. I expect the information that is sent from the server to client when the below line runs to set some cookies in the browser.

```
            await database_sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()
            await self.send(simplejson.dumps(dict(data=dict(user=dict(username=user.username)))))
```

But it is not happening. What could be the issue?

Comment: what does {{ message is intended for login }} mean?

Comment: It is meant to check if the message is for logging in. As this same method is used to receive all messages from the client, this becomes necessary.